# How does string translation (localization) work for a specific language and locale?

Tags: android, localization, translation, translation-editor

The default language for my android app is English and the respective strings are stored in the default /res/values/strings/strings.xml

Now I wanted to support the french language so I opened the `Translation Editor` and added the translations for `French (fr)` locale.

But there seems to be multiple locale variants of french language(i.e. French in Algeria, French in Belgium ... etc) and I didn't added the translations for all these.

I just wanted to know, what language is shown to the users who has `French` as the default language on their devices but with a **specific locale** for which I don't have the specific translations.

Comment: They'll get the default `fr` folder(s) contents

Answer (score 0):

When a user has a more specific locale specified than the app does, then the localization should "fall back" to basic language definition, in your case, "fr."

You can test these things in a simulator.

As you know, this already happens with English, your default language... and you weren't worried about what happens if someone is set to en-GB, or en-AU.

Comment: Is there any official documentation that confirms this?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/multilingual-support